# Verification key for jose4j JwtConsumer

Tags: java, jwt, jose4j

I am using jose4j to validate and process a JWT. The JWT looks like the following and it passes the validation in the JWT homepage.
[image]

However, I can't do the same using jose4j java library. The exception complains about the verification key I set. But there are many types of keys defined in the library and I tried them but no luck. The code is as following:

```
import java.util.Map;

import org.jose4j.jwt.JwtClaims;
import org.jose4j.jwt.consumer.InvalidJwtException;
import org.jose4j.jwt.consumer.JwtConsumer;
import org.jose4j.jwt.consumer.JwtConsumerBuilder;
import org.jose4j.keys.HmacKey;

public class YGJWT {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InvalidJwtException {

        String jwt = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ";
        String secret = "secret";

        JwtConsumer jwtConsumer = new JwtConsumerBuilder()
                .setVerificationKey(new HmacKey(secret.getBytes())) //what kind of key do i need to use it here?
                .build();


        JwtClaims jwtClaims = jwtConsumer.processToClaims(jwt);
        Map<String, Object> claimsMap = jwtClaims.getClaimsMap();

        claimsMap.forEach((String key, Object val) -> {
            System.out.println(key + ": " + val.toString());
        });

    }

}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I 'd guess you're getting an Exception something like this?

> `org.jose4j.lang.InvalidKeyException: A key of the same size as the hash output (i.e. 256 bits for HS256) or larger MUST be used with the HMAC SHA algorithms but this key is only 48 bits`

The `HmacKey` is the correct type for `HS256` but the key is technically too short according to the second paragraph of https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518#section-3.2 which has the same text as the exception message.

You can work around it by building the `JwtConsumer` with `.setRelaxVerificationKeyValidation()`, which will allow for shorter keys.

That looks like this (adding just one line to a snippet from your example):

```
JwtConsumer jwtConsumer = new JwtConsumerBuilder()
     .setVerificationKey(new HmacKey(secret.getBytes())) 
     .setRelaxVerificationKeyValidation() 
     // allow shorter HMAC keys when used w/ HSxxx algs 
     .build();
```

In general though I would try and avoid the use of a short password like key such as "secret" and suggest using a stronger key when possible.

Comment: Glad I could help and thanks for using [the jose4j JWT library](https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/wiki/Home)!

Comment: @BrianCampbell if I may ask here -;) 
Am getting an exception when I try to get a JWT token '   
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this key: sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl

Comment: @AdetiloyePhilipKehinde, see the comment at https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/issues/51/jwt-token-no-installed-provider-supports